# OAuth 1.0 signature using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, oauth, ramda.js

I created an OAuth 1.0 signature generator using Ramda based on [this](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures).

I'm just getting to grips with it, so was wondering if someone more familiar with Ramda and functional programming would give me review.

```
const R = require('ramda')
const hmacsha1 = require('hmacsha1');

// For RFC 3986 Compliant URI Encoding.
let encode = R.pipe(
  encodeURIComponent,
  R.replace(/\!/g, '%21'),
  R.replace(/\'/g, '%27'),
  R.replace(/\(/g, '%28'),
  R.replace(/\)/g, '%29'),
  R.replace(/\*/g, '%2A')
);

// Create a random alphanumeric string of a given length.
let nonce = R.pipe(
  R.times(
    R.partial(
      chars => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)],
      [ '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ]
    )
  ),
  R.join('')
);

// Return the current timestamp in seconds
let now = R.pipe(
  Date.now,
  R.flip(R.divide)(1000),
  Math.floor
);

// Sort a list of pairs by the first item then the second.
let sortPairs = R.compose(
  R.sortBy(R.prop(0)),
  R.sortBy(R.prop(1))
);

// Encode a list of pairs.
let encodePairs = R.map(R.map(encode));

// Convert a list of pairs into a query string.
let toParams = R.compose(
  R.join('&'),
  R.map(R.join('='))
);

// Join key items with an ampersand and hash with given data.
let hash = R.pipe(
  R.join('&'),
  R.curry(R.binary(hmacsha1))
);

// Rename an objects keys
let renameKeys = R.curry((keysMap, obj) => {
  return R.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[keysMap[key] || key] = obj[key];
    return acc;
  }, {}, R.keys(obj));
});

// Convert arguments object to OAuth object.
let renameOAuthKeys = R.curry(renameKeys)({
  consumerKey: 'oauth_consumer_key',
  signatureMethod: 'oauth_signature_method',
  oauthToken: 'oauth_token',
  version: 'oauth_version',
});

// reverse concat
let fconcat = R.flip(R.concat);

// Prepend the method and url to the base string.
let prependRequest = R.pipe(
  R.adjust(R.toUpper, 0),
  R.adjust(R.compose(fconcat('&'), encode), 1),
  R.join('&'),
  R.concat
)

// Sort and encode the OAuth params.
let encodeParams = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  encodePairs,
  sortPairs,
  toParams,
  encode
);

// Create dynamic OAuth values.
let addDynamicKeys = R.curry(nonceSize => R.merge({
  oauth_nonce: nonce(nonceSize),
  oauth_timestamp: now(),
}));

// Create an OAuth 1.0 signature.
module.exports = ({
  consumerKey,
  consumerSecret,
  oauthToken,
  oauthSecret,
  url,
  params={},
  data={},
  method='POST',
  version='1.0',
  signatureMethod='HMAC-SHA1',
  nonceSize=32
}) => R.pipe(
    R.merge(R.merge(params, data)),
    renameOAuthKeys,
    addDynamicKeys(nonceSize),
    encodeParams,
    prependRequest([method, url]),
    hash([consumerSecret, oauthSecret])
  )({ consumerKey, signatureMethod, oauthToken, version, })
```

Full Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/adamjmcgrath/2640591d937e6a77c3cc2751f068e884)